# Removing duplicates using PigLatin

Tags: apache-pig

I'm using PigLatin to filter some records.

```
User1  8 NYC 
User1  9 NYC 
User1  7 LA 
User2  4 NYC
User2  3 DC
```

The script should remove the duplicate for users, and keep one of these records. Something like the unique command in linux.

The output should be:

```
User1 8 NYC 
User2 4 NYC
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For your particular example distinct will not work well as your output contains all of the input columns `($0, $1, $2)`, you can do distinct only on a projection that has columns `($0, $2)` or `($0)` and lose `$1`.

In order to select one record per user (any record) you could use a `GROUP BY` and a nested `FOREACH` with `LIMIT`. Ex:

```
inpt = load '......' ......;
user_grp = GROUP inpt BY $0;
filtered = FOREACH user_grp {
      top_rec = LIMIT inpt 1;
      GENERATE FLATTEN(top_rec);
};
```

This approach will help you get records that are unique on a subset of fields and also limit number of output records per each user, which you can control.

Answer (score 0):

Pig provide DISTINCT command to select unique data. If you want use distinct on fields Use Distinct in foreach nested block.

Comment: Be careful while using Distinct ..The drawback with DISTINCT keyword is : You cannot be sure that only first record will be removed.