# Hive where clause on Nth field

Tags: sql, hive, where-clause

I'm writing a simple select query in hive.
What i'm trying to do, is to filter by the value of the Nth (e.g. 5th) field, which I'm not sure what it's name will be, but I do know it's order.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have no knowledge of Hive, but as I understood from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11750312/hive-ql-limiting-number-of-rows-per-each-item), it would be somewhat similar to SQL Server.

```
SELECT field FROM

    (SELECT 
        field, 
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY [your order clause]) as row 
    FROM table_name
    Order by [your order clause])

WHERE row = 5
```